# Modem dropped in Raspberry Pi3 and I can find it anymore, despite it is visible with lsusb

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, modem, lte

So, I am facing a problem with several Rpi units I have here.

Most of the time they work fine, but after several days, the LTE modem (TELIT 910C1-LA) stops working with no reason.

Luckily, I could reproduce the problem and saw what is happening before it:

The system has booted
I have a HTML page that exhibits the modem status
LTE Modem had the status: "Connecting"
LTE Modem has changed the status to "Disconnecting"
LTE Modem has changed the status to blank
I have connected trought SSH to the Rpi and run some commands to check what was happening: [image: Comands I tried]

mmcli -L has returned "No modems were found"
mmcli -m 0 has returned "couldn't find modem at "
qmicli -d has returned the ICCID of the SIM Card
It seems to me that the modem has dropped, then I have connected SSH again an checked the lsusb: [image: lsusb show the modem in the usb list]

It is possible to see that the "Telit Wireless Solution" is conencted on the USB
Do you guys has any tips on that? I am kind of newbie to Linux OS, I know how to execute basic commands, but I am definetly not an advanced user.

Thanks in advance!

I did not tried anything, as I don't want the problem to go away before further analisys.

This is an intermitent problem and I want to understand why it is happening and how can I fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try resetting the modem with [usbreset](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/usbutils/usbreset.1.en.html) when you detect it is no longer working. Something like this:

```
ping -q -c 1 1.1.1.1 || usbreset 1bc7:1201
```

This example sends a ping request to 1.1.1.1 and if it fails (there is no answer) then usbreset is run, selecting the device by vendor:id.

Comment: Thank you, Eduardo!
I could restabilish the conection using usbreset. Now I am implementing a script to check the connection and reset the modem once a day.